# Turn off clearing aliases in Cypress test

Tags: cypress

We have a number of variables from the API which are used throughout the tests. The values are saved to aliases at various points.

How can we turn off clearing aliases between test?

If we use one big test this works fine but Cypress by default clears aliases between tests, so as we break down the tests into smaller more manageable units we are breaking the code.

Simple example:

```js
before(() => {
  cy.wrap(123).as('alias')
})

it('test1', () => {
  // alias is usable here
  cy.get('@alias').should('eq', 123)    
  cy.wrap(456).as('alias2')
});

it('test2', () => {
  // alias is missing here
  cy.get('@alias').should('eq', 123)    
  cy.get('@alias2').should('eq', 456)  
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no configuration to turn off alias cleardown.

You would have to create a custom command to do it.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('keepAliases', function(aliasList) {
  if (!aliasList) {
    aliasList = Object.keys(this)
      .filter(key => !['test', '_runnable', 'currentTest']
      .includes(key))
  }
  aliasList.forEach(key => {
    cy.wrap(this[key]).as(key)
  })
})
```

**Usage for a single test**

```js
before(() => {
  cy.wrap(123).as('alias')
})

it('test1', () => {
  cy.get('@alias').should('eq', 123)    
  cy.wrap(456).as('alias2')
});

// ✅ test passes 
it('test2', () => {
  cy.keepAliases()
  cy.get('@alias').should('eq', 123)  
  cy.get('@alias2').should('eq', 456)
});
```

**Usage for all tests**

```js
before(() => {
  cy.wrap(123).as('alias')
})

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.keepAliases()
})

it('test1', () => {
  cy.get('@alias').should('eq', 123)    
  cy.wrap(456).as('alias2')
});

// ✅ test passes 
it('test2', () => {
  cy.get('@alias').should('eq', 123)  
  cy.get('@alias2').should('eq', 456)
});
```

Comment: This does not work for me. as I see cypress cleans the aliases even before going to the beforeEach block for the 2nd test.

Comment: The code is still passing. Maybe you forgot to use `function()`. Also note there is a difference between alias cleardown and `this.aliasName` cleardown.

Answer (score -1):

According to [cypress doc](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Sharing-Context)

> aliases and properties are automatically cleaned up after each test

so with current cypress versions your goal is not achievable.

As a workaround you could use [cypress.env](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env#Syntax) as a storage for your tests:

```
Cypress.env(varName, varValue)
```

and using a test0 to reset all variables before each texts execution:

```
it('test0', () => {
  // clean up all stored aliases
  cy.env("var1",null);
  cy.env("var2",null);
  //...
});
```